# WSDL2Java. Apache CXF. ArrayOf{Type} to List<Type>

Tags: apache, wsdl, jaxb, cxf

How to generate `List<Type>` instead ArrayOf{Type} ?
For example method return

```cs
[WebMethod]
public List<long> GetSimple()
```

WSDL2Java will generate:

```java
public ru.test.ws.ArrayOfLong GetSimple();
```

ArrayOfLong:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfLong", propOrder = {
    "_long"
})
public class ArrayOfLong
    implements Serializable
{
    @XmlElement(name = "long", type = Long.class)
    protected List<Long> _long;

    public List<Long> getLong() {
        if (_long == null) {
            _long = new ArrayList<Long>();
        }
        return this._long;
    }
}
```

How to configure CXF and JAXB to use `List<Long>` instead ArrayOfLong?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem currently

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1) make sure `<jxb:globalBindings collectionType="indexed"/>` **doesn't** exist. It will turn all collections to arrays.

2) try to force the type with the `@WebResult` annotation

Hope this helps.